# Eclipse: make ESC key focus on active code window

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse (version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)) I wonder if there is a way to map ESC key to focus on active code window.

I've seen this behaviour in NoSQLBooster and is really useful

Comment: Eclipse 2020-06 is two releases behind. Please upgrade. What do you mean by _active code window_? The active editor?

Comment: Active editor yes. In java perspective, current editing class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to map <kbd>Esc</kbd> (in addition to the default of <kbd>F12</kbd>) to focus on the active editor, do the following:

1. Window > **Preferences: General > Keys** (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice)
2. **Select** the ***Active Editor*** command
3. Click the ***Copy Command*** button
4. Set the focus into the ***Binding*** field and hit **<kbd>Esc</kbd>**
5. Click the ***Apply and Close*** button